# REST service wso2 DAS or CEP

Tags: web-services, wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi, wso2-cep

Can I make a calling of service REST, that use a parameter of other input stream of type HTTP from siddhi ?

For example:

I have a input stream sensorStream:

```
@Import('org.wso2.event.sensor.stream:1.0.0')
define stream sensorStream (meta_timestamp long, meta_isPowerSaverEnabled bool, meta_sensorId int, meta_sensorName string, correlation_longitude double, correlation_latitude double, humidity float, sensorValue double);
```

I want to use the attribute meta_sensorName as input for calling my web service:

```
meta_sensorName  = http://dinas.tomsk.ru/js/index.html?paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/

http://52.37.125.225:3000/phishing?url=meta_sensorName
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do that. When you add the HTTP publisher you will have to define the endpoint and it's not dynamically configurable.

Also, it's not possible to use data in events to configure publishers/receivers